# laptop with intel i915 gpu, screen random flickering pixels on builtin and external display

Tags: i915

I have a Lenovo V570 laptop with ubuntu 16.04 with flickering pixels on screen. I Tried with Windows 7 too gives the same problem, might be a hardware issue.

On Ubuntu 14.04  I had fixed it by using the VESA driver instead of i915, somehow I completely forgot what I did and now that I have upgraded to 16.04 the problem is back.

The flickering pixels are more pronounced when I move the mouse. Overall it makes the laptop almost unusable. If someone can point me how to go back to Vesa with a 1366x768 resolution that is fine too, since that does not seem to have this problem.

Comment: What prevents you from doing what you request (going back to VESA in 16.04)?

Comment: Karl, Well i dont know how to go back to VESA in ubuntu 16.04, basically i tried manually removing the i915.ko driver from /lib/modules/... folder and it switches to VESA mode, but that max it can do in that case is 1024x768 not the 1366x768 widescreen that i had managed to get working earlier with VESA and i cannot remember those steps for the life of me now.